# Set variable from script

Tags: bash, shell, var

I have a script "set_var.sh" written like this

```
#!/bin/bash

export NAME=release
export ROOT=/Volumes/name/dev/release
```

but if I run this set_var.sh from terminal, afterward I issue set command to check variables I could not find NAME and ROOT var be set.

I am wondering what is wrong in my case.

Comment: When you run it, all variables get defined within the scope of the execution. If you want these variables to remain in your session, you have to `source` instead.

Answer (score 0):

it was set in sub-shell.

you need

```
source set_var.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply *run* set_var.sh, it runs in its own shell which exits, losing the variables that were set.

If you want to change variables in your interactive shell, you can use:

```
source set_var.sh
```

or the shorthand,

```
. set_var.sh
```

This will execute the lines of the script as if they were typed into your interactive shell.

Note that when you "source" a file this way, it does not require the "shebang" on the first line.

Note also that this is feature exists in Bourne shell as well, but only in the short-form version.